# Count each values in each row after string_agg in SQL

Tags: sql, count, google-bigquery, string-aggregation

I have a SQL table with one column in the end. I group by id and string_agg titles.

```
 ID     Title
  1        a
  1        a
  1        b
  2        c
  2        a
```

I have this table below right now.

```
  Titles
  a,a,b
  c,a
```

I want to count each value in each row in string agg as a new column. I tried count distinct or Count("a") which returned count of all values in one row. My expected outcome would be

```
Titles count_a count_b count_c count_all
a,a,b    2       1       0        3
c,a      1       0       1        2
```

Is this possible to calculate in SQL?

Comment: do you have just three values for title column? just a, b and c?!

Comment: No, this is just an example, I have much more sometimes 70 sometimes 80.

Comment: so how below accepted answer will work for you? just curious

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. Yes, it worked very well. Why do you think it wouldn't work?

Comment: sure. no problem. as you are `@beginner` - i was just interested if you were able to make it work for 70-80 columns that you mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id, string_agg(title, ',' order by title) as titles,
       countif(title = 'a') as num_as,
       countif(title = 'b') as num_bs,
       countif(title = 'c') as num_cs,
       count(*) as total
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and solution. Totally skipped countif possibility. Thanks again!